# NoReverseMatch error while trying to reverse url with Model Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

I think the error has something to do with url pattern changes in django 2.0. 
Almost everything i found on Google uses old url patterns, so they're not helpful.

```
...models
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #music/add/
    path('add', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name="album-add")
    ]
```

And this is the form, i don't think anything's wrong with it, because when i fill out the form itself and click submit, on the list page it shows that it's been submitted.

```
 <form action="", method="post">
```

the error itself:

```
NoReverseMatch at /music/add/
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments **'{'pk': 11(id of the item i'm adding}'** not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['music/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Afterwards, i go to list directly and the item with id 11 is right there, i click it and it opens without any issues

detail pattern:

```
path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

Comment: Since the problem is with the "detail" URL, you actually need to show that URL pattern.

Comment: path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'), also edited into the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your detail URL pattern expects an `album_id` parameter but you are passing it `pk`. Correct your method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'album_id':self.pk})
```

or change the URL pattern:

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

(but don't do both).